# What am I missing in this proof? Unbiased vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, hilbert-spaces

I have a set of vectors $\{P_{1},P_2,...,P_{d+1}\}$ in a $d$-dimensional Hilbert space, which satisfy the following two conditions on the inner product
$$|P_{i}|^2=d, \quad \forall i=1,...,d+1,  \qquad \qquad P_i^*\cdot P_j =-1, \quad i,j=1,...,d+1 \text{ and } i\neq j.$$
I want to prove that this set is not linearly independent but if you remove any vector, it becomes linearly independent.

The first part of the proof is easy if one notices that any of the vectors can be written as
\begin{equation}
P_i=-\sum_{\substack{j=1\\ i\neq j}}^{d+1}P_j,
\tag{1}
\label{eq:pi}
\end{equation}
because this satisfies both conditions on the inner products.

Therefore, let us now remove $P_1$ from the set, for example. Is the set $\{P_2,P_3,...,P_{d+1}\}$ linearly independent? I would say that it is. Let us take $P_2$ for example and see if it can be written as a linear combination of $\{P_3,...,P_{d+1}\}$. From \eqref{eq:pi} we have that
$$P_2=-P_1-P_3-P_4-...-P_{d+1},$$
and this doesn't seem like it can be written as a linear combination of $\{P_3,...,P_{d+1}\}$. However, I feel that this proof is missing rigour somewhere.

What am I missing?

Comment: in short, what you are missing is the use of a *Gram Matrix* to encode the information about the inner products from your 2nd/3rd line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors $P_1 - P_{d+1}, \dots , P_d - P_{d+1}$ are all non-zero and orthogonal to each other, hence linearly independent:

Let $i,j<d+1$, $i\ne j$ then:
$$
\| P_i - P_{d+1}\|^2 = d + 2 + d = 2d+2>0
$$
$$
(P_i- P_{d+1},  P_j- P_{d+1}) = 0.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the $d+1\times d+1$ **Gram matrix** $G$ where $g_{i,j} := \langle P_i, P_j\rangle$
(or $g_{i,j} := \langle P_j, P_i\rangle$ depending on inner product convention)

And let $G'$ be $G$ with column $k$ and row $k$ deleted.

**(1)** Then $G= (d+1) \cdot I_{d+1} - \mathbf 1_{d+1}\mathbf 1_{d+1}^T$
$G\mathbf 1_{d+1}= \mathbf 0$ so $G$ is *singular*.

**(2)**  $G'= (d+1) \cdot I_{d} - \mathbf 1_{d}\mathbf 1_{d}^T$
and $G'$ is *nonsingular* because either  (i) strict diagonal dominance, (ii) Gershgorin discs, (iii) rank one update determinant formula, (iv) spectral decomposition, etc.

**(3)**  Finally use the correspondence between Gram matrix (non)singularity and vector linear (in)dependence, i.e. consider arbitrary $n\times n$ Gram matrix $G^{''}$ with $g^{''}_{i,j}:=\langle \mathbf v_i,\mathbf v_j\rangle$
$\mathbf x^* G^{''}\mathbf x = \sum_{i=1}^n \bar{x_{i}} \sum_{j=1}^n x_{j}\langle \mathbf v_i, \mathbf v_j \rangle = \langle\big(\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j} \mathbf v_j\big),  \big(\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j} \mathbf v_j \big)\rangle\geq 0 $
with equality *iff* $\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j} \mathbf v_j  = \mathbf 0$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I ask though what is $\mathbf 1_{d+1}$? From notation I would think it's a $d+1\times d+1$ matrix full of ones but this doesn't seem to give the right Gram matrix.

Comment: $\mathbf 1_{d+1}$ is the ones vector that lives $\in \mathbb C^{d+1}$... as a result $\mathbf 1_{d+1}\mathbf 1_{d+1}^T$ is exactly what you've guessed. (Alternatively, some texts would say let $J$ be the relevant sized ones matrix.) Note: old habits die hard and I inadvertently had used both $n$ and $d +1$ to deal with dimension for $G$ -- this is now fixed and hopefully cleaner.